# Flight duration from diffrent time zones

Tags: xquery, osb

I am facing the issue with time zones.
Code:

{

let $hour := hours-from-duration(fn:subtract-dateTimes-yielding-dayTimeDuration(xs:dateTime(data($FlightSegment/@ArrivalDateTime)),xs:dateTime(data($FlightSegment/@DepartureDateTime))))
            let $min := minutes-from-duration(fn:subtract-dateTimes-yielding-dayTimeDuration(xs:dateTime(data($FlightSegment/@ArrivalDateTime)),xs:dateTime(data($FlightSegment/@DepartureDateTime))))

return

```
    if($hour < 10  and $min < 10) then
        <flt-seg:FlightDuration> {concat('0',$hour,':','0',$min)}</flt-seg:FlightDuration>
        else if ($min < 10 ) then 
         <flt-seg:FlightDuration> {concat($hour,':','0',$min)}</flt-seg:FlightDuration>
         else if ($hour < 10 ) then
          <flt-seg:FlightDuration> {concat('0',$hour,':',$min)}</flt-seg:FlightDuration>
         else
          <flt-seg:FlightDuration> {concat($hour,':',$min)}</flt-seg:FlightDuration>


    }
```

Departure airport code is :BNE(Brisbane)

Arrival airport code is :LAX(Lass angels)

Response i am getting:

DepartureDateTime:2015-08-15T09:50:00

ArrivalDateTime:2015-08-15T06:30:00

FlightDuration: 0-3:0-20

flight duration (0-3:0-20) iam getting negative value, so request you to pls help me on this how can i get the positive value.

could you pls let me know how i will get proper flight duration with different time zones.
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Please take a look at the [markdown formatting help page](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#comment-formatting) - you can post code blocks by indenting by four spaces. It will make it much easier for people to understand what your code is doing.

Comment: Have a look at UTC dates...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you have *two* problems.

First problem is formatting the duration, which you can do using [functx:pad-integer-to-length()](http://www.xqueryfunctions.com/xq/functx_pad-integer-to-length.html) or using the [bea date functions](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E13190_01/liquiddata/docs85/xquery/extensions.html#1291970) (or number format functions) if you swing that way. That's the easy bit.

Your second, harder problem is your input data is airport-local, which cannot be compared the way you're doing it. You need to calculate the actual **UTC** date time from the local date time + port IATA code, probably via an interim lookup, so

1. airport -> [timezone ID](http://www.twinsun.com/tz/tz-link.htm) (cacheable)
2. port-local dateTime + tzID -> UTC dateTime.

It doesn't have to be UTC; as long as you're comparing dateTimes in the same time zone. However, UTC is a convenient timezone to choose, so it's probably best to use it.

Oh yeah. Make sure your OSB JVM has the latest tzdata or you'll find that your date calculation will be inaccurate for many destinations - Fiji loves to change daylight savings times at short notice.